# Using Graphics.DrawImage to create custom tabs in C#

Tags: c#, tabs

I have a project in which you can add and remove tabs (like a web browser). So far I have this:

```
//Button to add a new tab page
    private void cb_addPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString() + "   ";
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = myTabPage;
    }


//Form1_Load
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        cb_addPage.Top = tabControl1.Top;
        cb_addPage.Left = tabControl1.Right - cb_addPage.Width;
        foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages) tp.Text += "   ";
    }

    Rectangle closeX = Rectangle.Empty;

//Sets background and places the X button on each tab
    private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Size xSize = new Size(15, 15);
        TabPage tp = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];
        e.DrawBackground();
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tp.Text + "   ", e.Font, brush,
                                  e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 4);

        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            closeX = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Right - xSize.Width - 3, 
                           e.Bounds.Top + 5, xSize.Width, xSize.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[0], closeX, 
                         new Rectangle(0,0,16,16), GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
        }

    }

//Removes current tab (from X button)
    private void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (closeX.Contains(e.Location))
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
    }
```

So all this does is let you add tabs with a button and on each individual tab there is an `X` button to delete the tab.

I have used `Graphics.DrawImage` to display the custom `X` button (that are in an imageList). However how will I go about making custom tabs using `Graphics.DrawImage`.

To sum up I want tabs, but I want them to be custom images that I have made so it looks better. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Probably you want to display a different text on each tab. You can use the `TextRenderer` to do so:

```
const TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping |
    TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;

TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, tp.Text, tp.Font, e.Bounds, tp.ForeColor, flags);
```

Either prepend some spaces to the text in order to leave space for the X or define new coordiantes for the text

```
const int XCrossWidth = 20;
Rectangle textRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + XCrossWidth,  e.Bounds.Top,
                                   e.Width - XCrossWidth, e.Height);
```

and substitue this for `e.Bounds` in `TextRenderer.DrawText(...)`.

---

**UPDATE**

So you want to display custom images on your tabs. I assume that you have placed these images in the `imageList1`. How do you know which of them to display on which TabPage?

You could create your own tab page class and use this one instead of `TabPage`.

```
public TabPageEx : TabPage
{
    public int ImageIndex { get; set }
}
```

Now set the property to the appropriate image index.

```
TabPageEx myTabPage = new TabPageEx(title);
myTabPage.ImageIndex = 3; // As an example.
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
```

Then you can draw the image with

```
TabPageEx tp = (TabPageEx)tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

...

Rectangle imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 20,  0, 16, 16);
e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[tp.ImageIndex], imageRect);
```

Comment: Edited summary on the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display Images in addition to the text like a webbrowsers favicon you can use this modified code:

```
private void tabControl3_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Size xSize = new Size(16,16);
    Point imgLoc = new Point(e.Bounds.X +  4, e.Bounds.Y + 4);
    TabPage tp = tabControl3.TabPages[e.Index];
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[tp.ImageIndex], new Rectangle(imgLoc, xSize), 
                            new Rectangle(Point.Empty, xSize), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tp.Text + "   ", e.Font, brush, 
                              e.Bounds.X + 23, e.Bounds.Y + 4);
        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            closeX = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Right - xSize.Width - 3, 
                         e.Bounds.Top + 5, xSize.Width, xSize.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[0], closeX, 
                       new Rectangle(Point.Empty, xSize), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        }
    }
}
```

You need to make sure that:

- You have those images you want to show in each tab in your imagelist.
- and you know the index of ech one.
- Youi must set it when you create the page but you can always change it later.
- It is a good idea to have a default icon at index 0 and to set the imageindex to 0 for those you don't know the right index.

Usually you would also have to make your Tab control point to the Imagelist. But since we are drawing it all by ourselves, this is not important.

You can use the more complex format of `DrawString`, that is used for drawing the close button. Here you don't just use a point to determine the location where to draw; instead this format uses two rectangles to determine the source and the target. This effectively leads to th option of scaling the image to a new size.

But you'll get the best quality if your Images have the right size to begin with. Please note that the text of each `TabPage` determines the width of the tab; to make it higher you need to chose a larger Fontsize.

Comment: Ahh right, well I have a 135 x 30 picture (as shown here): http://gyazo.com/ac4bb80e71797cc2fc571fb5cadecfb7 . (Ignore the text on it, it is for testing). But this is the image and I was wondering if I can replace the tabs with that image for every tab. Also you where would I put the `e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList2.Images[e.Index], Point.Empty );`? I am not 100% sure on where it will go in my code.

Comment: Well, 30 pixels are a bit much for the height. But do you really want to show this images for each tab?? - And if all images only show text, you may as well change the Font to match the one in your image; that'll be a lot easier and, of course flexible.. The Background is siple to create for the text, too

Comment: Well, I was going to use it for a testing. I could quickly create a 80 x 15 or something

Comment: The font looks like Verdana. If you change the Tab control's font to Verdana 12-15 point all you need to add is a FillRectangle..

Comment: Oh right, well my ultimate goal was to display what was on the page in the tab (like a web browser) but I was going try and figure that out after, but if the font and the text play such a big part, is it worth trying to do it now? If so, will a text box have to be displayed on the tab then it is linked to a certain string the page?

Comment: No, the Text is a Property of the TabPage, as is its Font. Which browser can show a page in its tab?? Or do you mean the tiny favicons on the left of many browsers' tabs?? These can be shown by using the imagelist/imageindex properties of each page.

Comment: I mean for Google Chrome for example you have this: http://gyazo.com/e515d8b326b81eb1fb15116cf9fcc415 . On the tab which displays what is on that the page. But if not it is fine, my main goal now is to make the tabs into custom pictures.

Comment: Exactly! These are called 'FavIcons' and they are displayed for all wesites, that have one at their root. You can simply use the imagelist1 to hold them and use the code above. All you need to do is to shift the text by the width of the images, or prefix it with a few blanks.. You would need to decide on their index when you add the page so the paint routine can paint the right image. I'll show you the code later tonight or tomorrow morning..

Comment: Ahhh ok. Well how will I go about using a FavIcon combined with my image for my tabs? Because I am not to sure where to put the image for the tabs in my code.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? Note: I have added code to include the FacIcons..

Comment: Not yet, as I am unable to have access to the computer I am working on. I will be back on it in a few days.