# Tabbed Notepad - not able to remove close button

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, notepad

I'm trying to create a tabbed notepad application but having problems in deleting the "close buttons" on the tabs. The tabs gets removed as they should, but I'm only able to remove 1 close button. Can anyone please help and direct me into the right direction:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace My_Notepad
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    int TabCount = 0;
    int btx = 96;
    private int i;

    public void newBox()
    {

        TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Document          ");
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
        this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tp;
        this.tabControl1.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;


        Button btnPlay = new Button();
        this.btnPlay = btnPlay;

        btnPlay.Width = 16;
        btnPlay.Height = 18;
        btnPlay.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        btnPlay.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        btnPlay.Top = 25;
        btnPlay.Left = btx;
        btnPlay.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\\close-button.png");
        btnPlay.Click += new EventHandler(btnPlay_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(btnPlay);
        btnPlay.BringToFront();
        TabCount++;
        i++;

    }



    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Dispose();
        this.Controls.Remove(btnPlay);

    }


    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newBox();

        btx = btx + 126;
    }



    public Button btnPlay { get; set; }


   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be, that you don't keep separate references to the `Buttons` you create. The way you wrote the code, suggests that you have a class level variable `btnPlay`, to which you assign a dynamically created local variable `btnPlay`, thereby overwriting the reference to the old `Button`:

```
Button btnPlay = new Button();
this.btnPlay = btnPlay;
```

Later, when you try to delete the `Buttons`, you can only reach the last one.

To avoid this you need to keep references that connect each Button to the `TabPage` it refers to. The most common way is to use the `Tag` of your pages to hold a reference:

```
Button btnPlay = new Button();
this.btnPlay = btnPlay;  
tp.Tag = btnPlay;
```

Now you can reach it as long as the `TabPage` is still alive:

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnPlay = ((sender as TabPage).Tag as Button);
    ..
}
```

However, since all you want to do is get rid of it, there is an even simpler solution: In the `btnPlay_Click` event you have a reference to the correct `Button` via the `sender` param..:

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab.Dispose();
    (sender as Button).Dispose();
}
```

For this you don't even need to use the `Tag`.. Not sure if you do anything with the class level `btnPlay`..??

**However**..

..the way I read it, your code has one more problem: **Each** close button only closes the **currently** selected `TabPage` instead of the one it belongs to.. So what we actually need, is to keep a reference from each `Button` to its `TabPage`, not the other way round..:

```
Button btnPlay = new Button();
this.btnPlay = btnPlay;  // what is it good for?
btnPlay.Tag = tp;
```

Now this should work:

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnPlay = sender as Button;
    (btnPlay.Tag as TabPage).Dispose();
    btnPlay.Dispose();
}
```

Btw, if you are otherwise happy with your solution, by all means stick to it! Just wanted to mention, that usually one uses `owner drawing` the `TabControl` to add adornments like close buttons. Your way sounds a little simpler, I'd say, at least until you want to move or resize the Tab..

**Update**: since you asked about owner-drawing, here is a minimal example:

```
Rectangle currentCrossRect = Rectangle.Empty;

private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap cross = yourCloseImage;
    int xWidth = cross.Width;
    TabPage tp = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    Size size = tabControl1.ItemSize;
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tp.Text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds.Left + 2 , 5);
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tp)
    {
        currentCrossRect = new Rectangle( 
                           e.Bounds.Left + size.Width - 20, 3, xWidth,xWidth);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(cross, currentCrossRect.X, currentCrossRect.Y);
    }
}


private void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TabPage tp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

    if (currentCrossRect.Contains(e.Location)) tp.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hi TaW,

Thank you very much. I have applied your solution and is working great. I see now what you mean with when resizing and moving tabs - the buttons remains on previous location when closing tabs. I will play around and see if I can get past that, if not, I will have a look at owner drawing. Thanks again - much appreciated

Comment: Glad that is works for you. If you feel the question is answered, please consider marking it as accepted. For your further test you may want to have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399467/tab-page-header-location/30401414?noredirect=1#comment48894687_30401414)

Comment: Hi TaW,
Seems like I need to look at the owner drawing option as I can't get around what I currently have. Do you know of any good tutorials on owner drawing specific to close buttons for tabs? Thanks and regards.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327942/using-graphics-drawimage-to-create-custom-tabs-in-c-sharp/26328643?s=4|0.1472#26328643) is a solution that shows owner drawing. Note that it actually draws individual glyphs onto the Tabs, not just one 'X', so you should be able to simplify it. BTW: There are two ways to show closing buttons: Firefox sgow it on each page. VStudio only on the active tab. The latter is obviously simpler to get right..

Comment: While it ought to be in a separate question,  have added minimal code, using one x on the selected tab only..

Comment: Thank you TaW - you are a star. I have now used your above code and it works perfectly. I have managed to change it a bit so that each tab have an image with a click event. Much appreciated