# Tab Page Header Location

Tags: c#, location, tabcontrol

I have a Tab Control in my Form and what I want to achieve is a simple way to get the exact location the Tab Page Header.

I've searched around, but I haven't found anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider showing what you have done.

Comment: Well, I'd really like to provide you with some of my work, but none of the stuff that I have written is relevant to my problem, so no point in e.g. showing how to add a new tab page to my tab control.

Comment: For best advice you sholud tell us, what exactyl you want to achieve..

Comment: Well, I have a tabControl and the user can add a new Tab Page which contains a RichTextBox. However, the Tab Page has no Close Button. I was thinking that if I had the exact location of the Tab Page Header and since I know its width, I could easily create a button on the left side of the Tab Page Header (and then with a simple event close the Tab Page).

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: Well, I've been somewhat busy the last few days travelling, but I found some sort of solution. However, it doesn't really have anything to do with getting the position of the TabPage Header, so it's not a direct solution to my original question. It's a different approach than what I was looking for in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This will make the **Tab** control **blink** a little but it will return a list of bounding Rectangles for the pages' headers..

```
SortedDictionary<int, Rectangle> GetTabBounds(TabControl tab)
{
    SortedDictionary<int, Rectangle> bounds = new SortedDictionary<int, Rectangle>();
    TabDrawMode tdm = tab.DrawMode;
    tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    DrawItemEventHandler mit = (sl, el) => bounds.Add(el.Index, el.Bounds);
    tab.DrawItem += mit;
    tab.Refresh();
    tab.DrawItem -= mit;
    tab.DrawMode = tdm;
    tab.Invalidate();
    return bounds;
}
```

For a less exact result you may simply want to calculate them from the page index and tab item size..at least if your pages are all in one row.

Comment: Hm, I'm gonna take a closer look at the code when I have some time and tell you if it does what I need.