# Img in custom TabPage WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabpage

Im using the following Code to customize the TabPage Control in WinForms. Unfortunately i cannot add the images from the Imagelist. If i change the DrawMode back to Normal it works like a charm.

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Brush _textBrush;


        TabPage _tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

        Rectangle _tabBounds = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);


        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {

            _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
            e.DrawBackground();
        }


        Font _tabFont = new Font("Arial", 14.0f, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();
        _stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        _stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;


        g.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, _tabFont, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));
    }
```

I tried to add the imagelist into my code but my TabPage starts to blink without an image.

Comment: You forgot Graphics.DrawImage().

Comment: I don't see the ImageList or DrawMode in your code example.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm sorry, I didn't find a solution right away and with your approach I came across the following question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327942/using-graphics-drawimage-to-create-custom-tabs-in-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top)
With it I could solve my problem.